# Borel $\sigma$-field and Equality

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a Borel $\sigma$-field on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $\mathcal{C}$ be the collection of closed intervals on $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $\mathcal{B} = \sigma(\mathcal{C})$.

If I'm going to show containment, $\mathcal{B} \subset \sigma(\mathcal{C})$, I need to find an arbitrary closed set in $\mathcal{B}$ that is contained in $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$, but I'm not sure how to go about this... Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: If $a<b$ then $$[a,b] = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(a-\frac1n,a+\frac1n\right) \cup (a,b) \cup \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(b-\frac1n,b+\frac1n\right). $$

Comment: But how do you get the countably infinite intersections of these sets? I thought the only properties are $\emptyset \in \mathcal{B}$, $A \in \mathcal{B} \Rightarrow A^c \in \mathcal{B}$, and that countable unions are also included?

Comment: De Morgan's laws

Comment: I guess it must seem trivial to you, but how do you generate the open set $(a−\frac{1}{n},a+\frac{1}{n})$ as a complement of an open set? My understanding is that the Borel σ-field on the real line is the collection of the open intervals... Am I missing something with this definition?

Comment: I don't really get what you're asking. $\left(a-\frac1n, a+\frac1n\right)$ *is* an open interval. If you take the intersection over all $n$, then you get the singleton $\{a\}$.

As for De Morgan's laws, use them to prove that $\sigma$-algebras are closed under countable intersections, in general. It is a straightforward exercise.

Comment: This is my first class that has ever covered $\sigma$-algebras... And we never went over an exercise or proposition that showed it was also closed under countable intersections, it's still the first week of class. I thought I might have missed something

Comment: That is a fundamental fact that you should be familiar with :)

Comment: Good to know, I'll keep it in mind